# want the parent_id name - sql joins

Tags: sql, join

I have written a query to allow me to return a list of servers and the folders they are located in but I need to also return the parent folders which I'm struggling to do.

Here is the query I have written that correctly returns the folders and the servers.

```
SELECT      
      a.foldername ,
      a.[Description],
      b.foldername,
      b.server_name ,
      b.[description]
FROM    table a
JOIN table b
    ON a.folder_id = TheServer.folder_id 
WHERE a.server_type = 0   
    AND server_name IS NOT null
ORDER BY [Server Group], [Server name]
```

table a also have a column `parent_id` which is also a `folder_id`.

I want to list the `parent_id` folder name but am struggling.

Comment: I think you need to join on `table a` again. do you only need the parents or also the "grandparents" and their parents etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MSSQL 2005+?  You could use a recursive CTE if you need full hierarchies.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: yes I'm using sql 2008, ok that's a good idea, I'll look at that thanks